# Less-technical synonym for "timestamp"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I've already looked at [Is there a word for "a point in time"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112214/is-there-a-word-for-a-point-in-time/112216#112216), but there doesn't seem to be any answers other than "timestamp". While I agree that it is the most technically accurate description, is there a term that lends itself more to a business environment?

For example, I have a spreadsheet with a list of customer feedback. The date and time that each issue was reported is listed in a single column. What would be a good business-y name to call that column? I'm looking for something that means "timestamp" without using a term that could be…misconstrued…as overly technical.

**EDIT:** To be more specific and concise, I'm looking for a term that means "timestamp", is used more popularly in a business environment than "timestamp", and is generic enough to always mean "timestamp" with almost any data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just have it as *Time*. If you want to be specific then say *Time Log*, or *Logged Time* assuming that the word *log* isn't too technical.

[Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) is not a recent term and has been in existence for a very long time. I highly doubt it will be misconstrued as something 'too technical'.

Comment: I agree with both your points. I don’t consider _timestamp_ a particularly technical term at all in and of itself.

Comment: @Tucker Before I posted the question, I looked up the word _timestamp_ and saw the photo of the literal [time stamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) on Wikipedia. Sweet! In any case, terms that are "too technical" seem to evoke feelings of ignorance and oppression in the business place, especially when the business at hand is IT. I wanted to avoid that. While I agree that _timestamp_ is the most accurate word to use, people might feel like it's a term used in technical documentation. I really like _Time Logged_ and will probably use that. A specific datetime is still a specific time.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution might be to simply name it after the GMT offset, e.g. instead of naming the column as "Date", you name it as "GMT +8:00".

Other alternatives:

- **Date/Time** or **Date & Time**
- **Logged On**
- **On**
- **When**

Answer (score 3):

**Moment** doesn't work?

> a particular time : a precise point in time

Comment: I don't believe it will work in this instance. "Moment" sounds too odd to have as a column header in a spreadsheet of reported issues. Thanks though!

Comment: Too odd-sounding, Exactly... http://english.stackexchange.com/a/164233/8278

Answer (score 3):

Do you really want to describe the type of data you are showing or do you want a descriptive title for the column that shows 'The date the issue was reported' ?

If it's the former then timestamp is fine, you might need to make clear if it's UTC, UTC+offset, UnixTime or whatever.

If not then perhaps you should consider a column heading that is descriptive to the consumers of the report, perhaps

> Date Issue Reported

or

> Reported Date *(shorter, but easily confused with Report Date)*

or

> Don't worry too much about because just after you think it's all
>   perfect they'll ask you to change it anyway. :)

Comment: This is more of a software comment than an EL&U comment, but it's important to have a more descriptive column name than just "TimeStamp" or "time" or "moment". Time that _what_ happened?

Comment: @outisnihil I totally agree, had the OP simply asked for a synonym for timestamp; moment is one of my favourites (I use it in code), but he asked for 'What would be a good business-y name' and that leads us to 'What is most understandable to a non-technical reader'. The whole question should really be in an IT SE of some sort but I could see the IT crowd kicking it out as 'not technical enough' or replying 'ask your users'.

Comment: @Frank I like how you explained three different ways of looking at it (#3 is the most likely solution…). The phrase "Reported Date" sounds really good, but (noting the reasons I gave in the answer from @Wes), this might not be the best choice in this instance. For example, someone could copy the table to use as a template, and the Timestamp column might not exactly mean the time the row was "reported".

Answer (score 3):

For a column in a spreadsheet, try simply "**Date/Time"** or "**Date**" or "**Date & Time**".

Comment: While "Date/Time" and "Date & Time" are pretty specific, they seem a little too odd for this instance. Just "Date" would sound better as a header name, but the column contains both date and time, so it might not sound as accurate. I like this answer though.

Comment: I've actually been there and had to label a similar column