# What do you call a combination of date and time?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Those who know programming simply call this as DateTime. For example, "2015-12-22 03:11:25".

Instead of referring it to simply DateTime, is there any other suitable name?

Comment: You may like to have a look at the discussion under http://english.stackexchange.com/q/164227/48571 - I won't call it a duplicate, just relevant (potentially).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though perhaps awkward in some contexts, *[timestamp](https://www.wordnik.com/words/timestamp)* does fit your desired meaning.

> The date and time at which an event occurs or occurred, usually indicated in human-readable form, especially when used in a log to track events.

Comment: Timestamp can sometimes have a slightly different meaning, especially in databases: [Datetime Vs Timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp). But, for a non-programming context, it can be used interchangeably with datetime.

Answer (score 0):

I use "time" as it may include both date and time, but if you use just "date", the time is not necessarily included.

Comment: Well, never have I heard in my whole life someone comes up and say, the time now is 20th March 2015 3.45pm ...

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Chris. *Time* and *date* are no normally conflated in this manner. Could you point to others who follow your pattern?